# how to identify right and left hand handpose tensorflow

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

I'm using handpose for one of the project. I need to find the right and left hand to implement a feature.

I could find the back and front side of the hand by using the coordinates but with the same logic I failed to figure out it is left or right hand because the backside of the right and front side of the left hand look almost same .How to find right and left hand from the detected landmark.

I could see in mediapipe example model is returning left and right hand labels is there anyway to identify the same using TFJS version ?

Comment: It doesn't classify a hand whether it is the left one or the right one. A naive approach would be to assume that people would always be facing the camera with both their hands facing it, therefore hands detected closer to the left side of the image(inverted) would be the right hand and the other one would be the left hand.

Comment: Previous comment is right - but to add, you could combine `handpose` with any body detection model (e.g. `movenet`) and then map which hand from first model is closer to which hand from the second model.